# 'Maintain Audio Pitch' in Speed/Duration causes Audio Glitch

Tags: premiere, editing, audio, adobe, premiere-pro

When I change the *Speed/Duration* of an audio track and check *Maintain Audio Pitch*, I frequently get **a moment of louder audio immediately following the edit point**. This is very frustrating…

Here's [a screen recording.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCSLz.jpg)

As a workaround I tried adding…

- additional frames and…
- fades at the beginning of the audio, but the problem remains.

What I also tried:

- Updating from Premiere Pro version 15.4 to 22.2
- Removing all attributes and effects from audio clips
- Rendering and nest audio clips
- Exporting everything
- Deleting the Media Cache and Media Cache files
- Resetting the preferences

I can reproduce the exact same problem with an entirely new project and different audio files (I tried MP3 and WAV). As soon as I change *Speed/Duration* and check *Maintain Audio Pitch*, the glitch appears.

What can I do to fix this?